# VBA - extracting data from multiple excel sheets

Tags: vba, excel

*UPDATE

The answer provided helped but I had some issues in it locating excel files within the folder. I've used a Dialog box to allow to user to select the folder to assist with this, which seems to have worked, but I am now receiving a run time error 438 (object doesnt support this property or method). This occurs after the first excel workbook is opened from the folder (FileToOpen = Workbooks.Open(Fold))

I've provided my updated code below. Any thoughts on how to amend?

**Prior post:**
*I am having a few issues updating my code to enable me to select / perform the action for multiple excel sheets. The code itself is designed to open up an excel book, copy the appropriate data into the 'database' and close it back down. 
What I would like it to do is loop through each workbook within a specific folder, undertaking the same action on each occasion, until all workbooks have had the data extracted.
Appreciate some help!*

**Code as follows:**

```
Sub ImportData()
'This sub is designed to pull the data from the respective spreadsheets into the Database
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Dim FolderPath As FileDialog
Dim Fold As String
Dim Directory As String


Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
Application.ScreenUpdating = True
'select the path to the folder you want

Set FolderPath = Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    With FolderPath
      .Title = "Select A Target Folder"
      .AllowMultiSelect = False
        If .Show <> -1 Then GoTo NextCode
        Directory = .SelectedItems(1) & "\"
    End With

NextCode:
  Fold = ""

Fold = Dir(Directory)

Do While Fold <> ""
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
FileToOpen = Workbooks.Open(Fold)

    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FileToOpen)
        For Each sheet In wb1.Sheets
            With sheet.UsedRange
                Loopy = Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
            End With
        Next sheet

        L = wb1.Sheets("Database").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1

        'Name
        wb2.Sheets("Feedback").Range("D4").Copy
        wb1.Sheets("Database").Range("B" & L).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        'Paper
        wb2.Sheets("Feedback").Range("D5").Copy
        wb1.Sheets("Database").Range("C" & L).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        'Date
        wb2.Sheets("Feedback").Range("D6").Copy
        wb1.Sheets("Database").Range("D" & L).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        'Completed by
        wb2.Sheets("Feedback").Range("D7").Copy
        wb1.Sheets("Database").Range("E" & L).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        'rating
        wb2.Sheets("Feedback").Range("J20").Copy
        wb1.Sheets("Database").Range("F" & L).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        'qualifiers
        wb2.Sheets("Feedback").Range("C17").Copy
        wb1.Sheets("Database").Range("G" & L).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        wb2.Sheets("Feedback").Range("D17").Copy
        wb1.Sheets("Database").Range("H" & L).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        wb2.Sheets("Feedback").Range("E17").Copy
        wb1.Sheets("Database").Range("I" & L).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        wb2.Sheets("Feedback").Range("F17").Copy
        wb1.Sheets("Database").Range("J" & L).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        wb2.Sheets("Feedback").Range("G17").Copy
        wb1.Sheets("Database").Range("K" & L).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        wb2.Sheets("Feedback").Range("H17").Copy
        wb1.Sheets("Database").Range("L" & L).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        wb2.Sheets("Feedback").Range("I17").Copy
        wb1.Sheets("Database").Range("M" & L).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        wb2.Sheets("Feedback").Range("J17").Copy
        wb1.Sheets("Database").Range("N" & L).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        'comments
        wb2.Sheets("Feedback").Range("B18").Copy
        wb1.Sheets("Database").Range("O" & L).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

    wb2.Close
Fold = Dir()
Loop

End Sub
```

Comment: I believe "Fold" needs to be a variant. Also, I do not see "FileToOpen" declared anywhere in the sub procedure. Have you checked either of these? Also, what is the value of "Directory" at the line where you get the error?

Comment: Hi Kyle, thanks again. I'm a little stumpted! I've changed Fold to variant, and tried defining FileToOpen as string (although I believe it worked previously when not defined). Directory is the folder path where the excel files are held :)

Comment: I understand what "Directory" is, but what is the string that it holds when your error occurs? If you do not know, type "Debug.Print Directory" in the line before the error. This will show the string stored in the variable "Directory" at the time of the error. Nothing looks wrong to me in your code, so I have a feeling it has to do with a variable.

Answer (score 1):

This will loop through each file in whichever path you put in "Dir()" and process as your code previously did. You may need to add decision making to decide which files you want to process as this will go through every file in the folder.

```
Sub ImportData()
'This sub is designed to pull the data from the respective spreadsheets into the Database
Dim wb1 As Workbook
Dim wb2 As Workbook
Dim sheet As Worksheet
Dim FolderPath As String
Dim Fold as Variant



Set wb1 = ActiveWorkbook
'opens a file select box
Fold = Dir("C:/User/Folder Name/") ' Change the path to the folder you want

Do While Fold <> ""

FileToOpen = Workbooks.Open(Fold)

If FileToOpen = False Then
    MsgBox "No File Specified.", vbExclamation, "ERROR"
    Exit Sub
Else
    Set wb2 = Workbooks.Open(Filename:=FileToOpen)
        For Each sheet In wb1.Sheets
            With sheet.UsedRange
                Loopy = Range("B1").End(xlDown).Offset(1, 0)
            End With
        Next sheet

   L = wb1.Sheets("Database").Cells(Rows.Count, "B").End(xlUp).Row + 1

        'Sheet names & cell copy and pastes
        wb2.Sheets("Feedback").Range("D4").Copy
        wb1.Sheets("Database").Range("B" & L).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        'Paper
        wb2.Sheets("Feedback").Range("D5").Copy
        wb1.Sheets("Database").Range("C" & L).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        'Date
        wb2.Sheets("Feedback").Range("D6").Copy
        wb1.Sheets("Database").Range("D" & L).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        'Completed by
        wb2.Sheets("Feedback").Range("D7").Copy
        wb1.Sheets("Database").Range("E" & L).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        'rating
        wb2.Sheets("Feedback").Range("J20").Copy
        wb1.Sheets("Database").Range("F" & L).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues
        'qualifiers
        wb2.Sheets("Feedback").Range("C17").Copy
        wb1.Sheets("Database").Range("G" & L).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        wb2.Sheets("Feedback").Range("D17").Copy
        wb1.Sheets("Database").Range("H" & L).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        wb2.Sheets("Feedback").Range("E17").Copy
        wb1.Sheets("Database").Range("I" & L).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        wb2.Sheets("Feedback").Range("F17").Copy
        wb1.Sheets("Database").Range("J" & L).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        wb2.Sheets("Feedback").Range("G17").Copy
        wb1.Sheets("Database").Range("K" & L).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        wb2.Sheets("Feedback").Range("H17").Copy
        wb1.Sheets("Database").Range("L" & L).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        wb2.Sheets("Feedback").Range("I17").Copy
        wb1.Sheets("Database").Range("M" & L).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        wb2.Sheets("Feedback").Range("J17").Copy
        wb1.Sheets("Database").Range("N" & L).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

        'comments
        wb2.Sheets("Feedback").Range("B18").Copy
        wb1.Sheets("Database").Range("O" & L).PasteSpecial xlPasteValues

End If

    wb2.Close
Fold = Dir()
Loop
End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks - unfortunately, this keeps skipping the code i.e. although there are files within the folder, it does not appear to be picking these up. Could there be an issue with using 2003 excel files instead of 2007+?

Comment: Unfortunately, after edits, now getting a run time error. Updated question submitted. Thanks for your help Kyle